# How to calculate Impulse direction towards tap position in SWIFT?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, position, tap

Trying to trigger shooting towards tap position in `SpriteKit`.
Having trouble calculating `CGVector`s, need some help.

I have the player position : `player.position`
I have the tap location: `tap.location`

Want to apply an impulse like this:

```
self.bullet.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(19, 0)
self.bullet.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(19, 0))
```

Not sure how to write up the calculation of the vector in Swift. Could you guys point me in the right direction? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

```
let vector = CGVectorMake(tap.location.x - player.location.x, tap.location.y - player.location.y)
self.bullet.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(vector)
```